# How to change the frame of a view with animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am a beginner. I am updating the frame of a view. I am a bit confused about animations. I just want to know how to update the frame of a view with any kind of animations.

This is where I am updating my frames:

```
- (IBAction)btnCountries:(id)sender {

    _dropDownView.hidden =  NO;
    fromCountry=YES;
    fromCity = NO;
    fromState = NO;
    _dropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(132.0f, 63.0f, 172.0f, 308.0f);

    [self.tblDropDown reloadData];

}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use : `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: block`

Comment: So many questions about animations on SO and you haven't found any?

Comment: Thanks to them who have voted down. I will learn from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIView method animationWithDuration:
or CoreAnimation framework.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        // animation here
        _dropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(132.0f, 63.0f, 172.0f, 308.0f);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                 animations:^{

                                    _dropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(132.0f, 63.0f, 172.0f, 308.0f); 

                                 }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];



                                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView support animation like as follows,

```
_dropDownView.hidden =  NO;fromCountry=YES;
fromCity = NO;
fromState = NO;

UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^
{
    _dropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(132.0f, 63.0f, 172.0f, 308.0f);
} completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    [self.tblDropDown reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
- (IBAction)btnCountries:(id)sender {

    _dropDownView.hidden =  NO;
    fromCountry=YES;
    fromCity = NO;
    fromState = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = _dropDownView.frame;
                         frame=CGRectMake(132.0f, 63.0f, 172.0f, 308.0f);
                         _dropDownView.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.tblDropDown reloadData];
                     }];

}
```

Hope it helps you..